# How to write this constrain in CVX

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, cvx

I don't know how to describe the following constrain in CVX:
$$
M = bb^H
$$
here $b$ is a complex column vector, and $b^H$ is the Hermitian transpose vector of $b$.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that constraint is convex?

Comment: You'll find this useful: http://ask.cvxr.com/t/why-isnt-cvx-accepting-my-model-read-this-first/570

Comment: Yes you are right, so how can I relax this constraint so that the CVX can accept it?

Comment: That's a new question, I'd say—and also not specific to CVX. You're basically asking if there is a standard way to relax this non-convex constraint to a convex form. Consider editing your question to reflect this.